# Centring an image in a viewport regardless of viewport width

Tags: html, css

I have an image slideshow that I am trying to centre in the viewport, regardless of the viewport's width. This is easily achieved if the viewport is wider than the image by using `margin: auto;`, however, when the viewport is narrower than the image, like on a tablet in portrait mode, the image butts up against the left margin and does not centre.

Centred in landscape mode:

[image]

Centred in portrait mode:

[image]

This is the HTML:

```
    <div id="slidebound">
    <div class="slider">
        <img src="images/slider/slide04.png" alt=""/>
        <img src="images/slider/slide03.png" alt=""/>
        <img src="images/slider/slide02.png" alt=""/>
        <img src="images/slider/slide01.png" alt=""/>
    </div>
    </div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
    #slidebound {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .slider {
        width: 1024px;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .slider img {
        position: absolute;
        animation: slider 32s infinite;
        opacity: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    @keyframes slider {25% {opacity: 1;} 40% {opacity: 0;}}
    .slider img:nth-child(4) {animation-delay: 0s;}
    .slider img:nth-child(3) {animation-delay: 8s;}
    .slider img:nth-child(2) {animation-delay: 16s;}
    .slider img:nth-child(1) {animation-delay: 24s;}
```

Comment: So, you want to centre image. Am i Correct? Have you tried display: flex; align-content: center; etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). But as a alternative, as you know the height and width you can use position and negative margins:

```
position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-512px;
top:50%;
margin-top:-150px;
```

[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/vLmjx37t/).

Comment: Thanks, Alex. That is what I'm looking for... however, a horizontal scrollbar is showing with this solution, even though we have `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: There shouldn't be and there isn't on the fiddle.

Comment: I've just tried it on the actual code and you're right... no scrollbars!

Answer (score 1):

As per i understand, you want your image to appear in center, no-matter what the screen size is. For this you can try below code:

```css
#slidebound {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .slider {
        width: 1024px;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .slider img {
        position: absolute;
        animation: slider 32s infinite;
        opacity: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    @keyframes slider {25% {opacity: 1;} 40% {opacity: 0;}}
    .slider img:nth-child(4) {animation-delay: 0s;}
    .slider img:nth-child(3) {animation-delay: 2s;}
    .slider img:nth-child(2) {animation-delay: 3s;}
    .slider img:nth-child(1) {animation-delay: 4s;}
```

```html
 <div id="slidebound">
    <div class="slider">
        <img src="http://abload.de/img/a6aawu.jpg" alt=""/>
        <img src="https://nxworld.net/example/css-image-hover-effects/pic01.jpg" alt=""/>
        <img src="http://abload.de/img/a6aawu.jpg" alt=""/>
        <img src="https://nxworld.net/example/css-image-hover-effects/pic01.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. With this solution, the image is resizing and that is what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Are you ok in using flex for your case? It depends on what browsers you need to support. You can check it out using caniuse.
In the meantime, here is a sample

https://codepen.io/hellouniverse/pen/QxwNWv

where I have centred one image both vertically and horizontally to show the way

```
#slidebound {
    height: 100vh;
}

.slider {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: inherit;
}


<div id="slidebound">
    <div class="slider">
        <img src="https://naomisimson.com/wp-content/uploads/image-placeholder.jpg" alt="" />

    </div>
</div>
```